# implementing delete operation in web grid

Tags: javascript, webgrid, delete-row

I am implementing deletion functionality on web grid.
I have a column which has a link delete when it is clicked a JavaScript function is called which sends the id of that record to controller who calls a remove method to delete that record but when i debug the code list of vehicles are returned but when delete link is clicked 
it gives a error A data source must be bound before this operation can be performed.

view:

```
 @model IEnumerable<ParkOnMyDrive.Models.Vehicle>
 @{
ViewBag.Title = "ViewVehicle"
   }
 <h2>ViewVehicle</h2>


  @{        
 var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model,
            defaultSort: "make",
            rowsPerPage: 3);
    }
   <h2>Vehicle List</h2>
  <div id="grid">
   @grid.GetHtml(
    tableStyle: "grid",
    headerStyle: "head",
    alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
    columns: grid.Columns(
             grid.Column("vehicleType","Type"),
             grid.Column("make", " Make"),
             grid.Column("modelType", "Model"),
             grid.Column("color", "Color"),
             grid.Column("registartion", "Registartion"),
             grid.Column(
             header: "Action", 
             format: @<text> 
          <a href="#" id="Delete_@item.vehicleId" >Delete</a></text>)
    )
)
```

Controller:

```
                [HttpPost]
             public ActionResult DeleteVehicle(string vehcKey)
             {

        //string key = "eb306a32-1be0-47ad-a0e8-756af97643b8";

        Vehicle vehicleModel = new Vehicle();
        string userName = "wasfa_anjum@yahoo.com";
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            bool success = vehicleModel.RemoveVehicle(vehcKey,userName);
            if (success)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Vehicle deleted successfully");
            }

            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Vehicle not deleted");
            }
        }
        else
        {
        }


        return View();
    }
```

Model

```
         public bool RemoveVehicle(string vehicleKey,string userName)
            {
        bool success = false;

        using (var session = MvcApplication.Store.OpenSession())
        {


            var removeVehicle = from vehc in session.Query<Vehicle>()
                                where vehc.vehicleId == vehicleId
                                where vehc.userId == userName
                                select vehc;
            if (removeVehicle.Count() > 0)
            {
                var myVehicle = removeVehicle.FirstOrDefault();
                Session.Delete(myVehicle);
                Session.SaveChanges();

                success = true;
            }
        }
```